# Deformation retract

Tags: analysis, differential-geometry, manifolds

How to prove that $r_t$ is a deformation retract

[image]

$M^a=\lbrace q\in M ; f(q)\leq a\rbrace$

We have the definition :

$r_t$ is a difformation retract if:

- $r_t$ is a continius ,onto application and $r_t(q)=q , \text{for }q\in M^a$ ,
- there exist an continuous application $H: M^b\times [0,1]\rightarrow M^b$ such that $H(q,0)=i_{M^a}\circ r(q); H(q,1)=I_{M^b}(q)$

M is a manifold .

$q$ and $\varphi$ are continuous so $r_t$ is continuous , but how to see that $r_t$ is onto ?

***I proved that $r_0$ is the identity and $r_1$ is a retraction from $M^b$ to $M^a$ 
how to deduce that $r_t$ is a deformation retract ?***

Please

Thank you

Comment: It seems to me that $M^a \subseteq M^b$ so that if $x \in M^a$ then by definition $r_t(x) = x$.

Comment: yes, this for onto ?